# Не работает PopUp окно

Tags: javascript

Код PopUp окна:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('.call_popup').click(function() {
    $('.popup').toggleClass('open');
  });
  $('.popup_header i').click(function() {
    $('.popup').removeClass('open');
  })

});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 200px 0 rgba(32, 19, 45, 0.90);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50%-125px);
  left: calc(50%-125px);
}

.popup.open {
  display: block;
}

.popup_header {
  position: relative;
}

.popup_header i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="call_popup"><ins>Узнать свой размер</ins>
```

И все бы ничего, только при нажатии на ссылку, не срабатывает JavaScript, в консоли выдает все окей, без ошибок, пишет jQury installed и так далее. Кто поможет разобраться в проблеме ?

Comment: Да видимо забыл , вообщем решил с помощью плагина на Wordpress PopUp Builder , все сработало

Answer (score 0):

Может вы забыли добавить элемент `.popup` У меня все работает:

```js
$('.call_popup').click(function() {
  $('.popup').toggleClass('open');
});

$('.popup_header i').click(function(){
  $('.popup').removeClass('open');
})
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 200px 0 rgba(32,19,45,0.90);
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50%-125px);
  left: calc(50%-125px);
}

.popup.open {
  display: block;
}

.popup_header {
  position: relative;
}

.popup_header i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="call_popup"><ins>Узнать свой размер</ins>

<div class="popup">
  123
</div>
```